# Google Maps in Android Application in Intellij 15

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea

I know that there are tons of questions like this however I could not find any of accepted answers useful.

I have tried ( and a few others as well ):

1. stackoverflow.com/questions/17960315/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-intellij-idea-12-and-13/17977734#17977734
2. stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable/15826818#15826818
3. stackoverflow.com/questions/14002488/google-play-services-library-in-intellij-12

But nothing so far works ... I do not know if this is an intelliJ 15 problem or mine.

Here are some screenshots

i.stack.imgur.com/Wfm9k.png

i.stack.imgur.com/bcShb.png

i.stack.imgur.com/SNkSZ.png

I have tried by importing it as a module directly from the android-sdk/extras/ ...., I have tried copying and pasting the whole google-services project into my workspace nothing works. The screenshots are just from the last setUp (tutorial/answer) I found and tried.

Here is the current error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hci4.project.FriendsWithCars/hci4.project.FriendsWithCars.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment
```

Please help me.

EDIT 1: 
Here is a new error in a new setUp ....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GoogleMap map;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Testing
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TESTING);
    DBHandler db = DBHandler.getInstance(this);
    String output = db.getFullDB();
    tv.setText(output);

     map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
}
}
```

Here is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TESTING"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
/>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hci4.project.FriendsWithCars-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
```

Comment: Quickest solution: Get Android Studio :)

Answer (score 0):

Side questions: 1. What is your setup? 2. How are you importing GMS?

I think your problem is you are calling the fragment before it is created and much less before it is attached. Do not call it onCreate(). Call it after onActivityCreated().

You might need something like inside `onActivityCreated()`

```
            // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
            MapFragment map= (MapFragment )
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (map== null) {
                // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                map= MapFragment .newInstance();

                // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                // with this one inside the frame.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.map, map);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work. For future reference here is what I did:

1. Download "Google play services" and "google repository" and "google support library" from the SDK Manager
2. Go to android-sdks/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject and copy the google-play-services_lib directory
3. Paste the directory somewhere on your system ( I pasted it at the same level as my project root )

../google-play-services_lib/

../Project/

../Project/.git

../Project/src

4. Go to Project Settings (cmd + ;) and go to Modules
5. Press the + above the middle column to add a new Module
6. Choose "Import Module"
7. Select the path to the **PASTED** google-services directory
8. A series of questions from IntelliJ on which you replay NEXT
9. If IntelliJ asks you to either **Reuse** or **Override** the .idea/.iml files select **Reuse*
10. Return to Project Structure/ Modules and select your Main Module
11. Press + on the bottom above "Dependencies storage format" and choose "Module"
12. Select the google-services module
13. Press the + again and select "Jars ... "
14. Give the path to the .jar in the pasted google-services directory (must be under libs)
15. Move google-play-services_lib to the top of the List

In the end it must look like this 
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoB27.png)

All the permissions you need ( They go above the  in AndroidManifest ... )

```
<permission
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

All the application settings you need (they go into the )

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY-FROM-GOOGLE" />
```

I hope this helps people ...